# Cold water coming from hot water taps

Tags: plumbing

In the whole building I have hot water no problem, but the two sinks closest to the boiler have stone cold water coming from the hot water taps. (No plumbing has been done in the building for the pass 6 months.) This just happened about a week ago. Looking for ideas.

Ok so the system is run off a boiler system, temp is set to 140, then there is a mixing valve that is set at 120. Only the 2 sinks closest to the boiler is cold. The rest is nice and hot.

Comment: Possible safety feature failing on a thermostatically controlled tap failing or that branch has debris in the valves stopping the hot.

Comment: It would really help if you'd tell us something about your water heater and related plumbing. Imagine us sitting here guessing based on almost no information. Please revise your post to do so.

Comment: Is the mixing valve only controlling flow to the two problem sinks? If so, the valve is malfunctioning and should be replaced.

Comment: The mixing Valve, controls the whole building